# WSS 2.0 web site all the list edit function doesn't work suddently

Tags: sharepoint, wss-2.0

I got this prolbem, the edit doesn't work in all the lists of the sharepoint web sites, I can still access the "edit", and save it, but the change is not there. 
New item can be created, all the others looks fine except the edit.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Glad you could work it out! Be careful with making changes to the SharePoint database as weird stuff like this can happen. Also not supported by MS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's unusual... and unfortunately WSS 2.0 doesn't give much logging. Are there any errors being reported in the Application log of the Event Viewer on the server? It could also be permissions.

What type of list is it? If it's an issues list perhaps something has gone wrong in the list view that is hiding the most recent changes.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have found the reason, it is due to a trigger attached to the table. So nothing to do with WSS.